# How to update this field map "status" to "online"

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Im new to firebase and I didn't understand to add the location to update the status from offline to online which is in map field.
Refer pic below[image]

I tried

```
db.collection('customers').document('B').update({
"machines": { "B1": {status: "online"} } }
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Your code replaces the entire `machines` field with the value you specify.

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects), you can use the "[dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#dot_notation)" to reference nested fields within the document.

In your case:

```
db.collection('customers').document('B')
.update(
   { "machines.B1.status": "online"}
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Is it possible to make it dynamic? Because here B an B1 are hardcoded, is it possible to make it like they can take any document or machine value? My B and B1 are coming from another variable